# Excel Macro not recognizing change in Dynamic Bloomberg Data

Tags: excel, vba, bloomberg

I wrote a simple macro in Excel that records a change in a cell with a date.
The macro works when the value in the cell is typed or changes through a formula.

When I use dynamic data from the Bloomberg API, and the data changes in Excel, the macro doesn't recognize the change in the cell and doesn't record it.

```
Dim xVal As String  
Dim iVal As Integer  
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)  
    Static xCount As Integer  
      iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Range("F:F"), 1)  
      xCount = iVal  
    Application.EnableEvents = False  
    If Target.Address = Range("C2").Address Then  
        Range("E3").Offset(xCount, 0).Value = Range("C2").Value  
        Range("F3").Offset(xCount, 0).Value = Now  
        xCount = xCount + 1  
    Else  
        If xVal <> Range("C2").Value Then  
        Range("E3").Offset(xCount, 0).Value = Range("C2").Value  
        Range("F3").Offset(xCount, 0).Value = Now  
        xCount = xCount + 1   
        End If  
    End If  
    Application.EnableEvents = True  
End Sub  
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)  
    xVal = Range("C2").Value  
End Sub
```

Comment: `...or changes through a formula.` How are you tracking that?

Comment: Changes are done by the bloomberg API via a different route and it doesn't trigger the `Worskheet_Change` events. You could run a task every x seconds to check if the content has changed and do whatever you need if it has. A possibly better way would be to create a subscription in your code directly - you will then receive events directly in your code every time the value changes.